# Orange Spots on Monstera Deliciosa

Tags: monstera, rust

I got a Monstera Deliciosa a few months ago and it’s been doing ok, recently I realized that a few leaves have a bunch of orange ish spots on them  and the underside of the leaves looks even worse, kinda like it’s rusty? :( I‘m not really sure what it is and what to do against it. I took a few pictures that show the problem.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Any sign of pests? Thrips for example, very very tiny white, brown insects. They look like dust so you should inspect very closely.

Comment: Yeah looks like thrips and ime they love monstera

Answer (score 1):

This looks like spider mite damage. It's the leaf undersides that are the most telling. Insecticidal soap, sprayed and thoroughly "massaged" by hand and paper towel, will ensure full coverage. Repeat in 5 days, then 5 days after that. You'll have eliminated their generational egg cycles that way and should be in the clear.